# Agrupar TextViews e depois acessá-los

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, view

Exemplo:

Tenho 3 `TextViews` e suas `id's`:

```
TextView tv1 -> id: "um"
TextView tv2 -> id: "dois"
TextView tv3 -> id: "tres"
```

Gostaria de agrupá-los de alguma forma que possa acessá-los através do grupo, ex.:

```
ViewGroup vg;
vg.addView(tv1);
vg.addView(tv2);
vg.addView(tv3);

TextView tv11 = (TextView) vg.findViewById("um");
TextView tv22 = (TextView) vg.findViewById("dois");
TextView tv33 = (TextView) vg.findViewById("tres");
```

É possível fazer isso? Tentei por `ViewGroup`, mas não consegui.

**SOLUÇÃO:**
A partir da resposta do @ramaral, meu código ficou assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) adapter.getViewAtPosition(i); //pega os layouts
        for (int j = 0; j < vg.getChildCount(); j++) { //percorre seus elementos
            View v = vg.getChildAt(j);
            if (v instanceof ViewGroup) { //pega tudo que for ViewGroup, inclusive outros layouts
                for (int h = 0; h < ((ViewGroup) v).getChildCount(); h++) { //percorre novamente
                    View v2 = ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(h);
                    if (v2 instanceof TextView) { //pega tudo que for TextView
                        map.put(v2.getId(), (TextView) v2); //adiciona as TextViews no HashMap
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Agora tenho acesso às `TextView's` de vários *layouts* e seus `id's` `(a1, a2 ... a70)` estão em ordem.

Comment: Onde foram criados esses `TextView`?

Comment: @ramaral Cada `TextView` em um layout diferente

Comment: Não consigo perceber qual a finalidade. Pode explicar melhor por que quer agrupá-los?

Comment: @ramaral tenho 7 *layouts*, cada um com cerca de 10 *TextViews*. Os *id's* deles estão em sequência (id's: a1, a2, ... a70). Se eu agrupá-los, acesso todos de forma mais fácil com um *for*, tipo isso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar um `HashMap` para guardar os `TextView`, usando como chave o ***id***:

```
Map<Integer,TextView> map = new HashMap<Integer, TextView>();
map.put(tv1.getId(), tv1);
map.put(tv2.getId(), tv2);
map.put(tv3.getId(), tv3);
```

Pode reaver cada um dos `TextView` usando o respectivo ***id***:

```
TextView tv = map.get(R.id.tv1);
```

Outra possibilidade é definir a chave variando de zero a n e depois utilizar ***for*** para aceder a cada um dos `TextView`

```
Map<Integer,TextView> map = new HashMap<Integer, TextView>();
map.put(0, tv1);
map.put(1, tv2);
map.put(2, tv3); 

for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
    TextView tv = map.get(i);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Podemos, em alternativa, obter todos os `TextView` em um *Layout* utilizando `ViewGroup.getChildAt()` e guardá-los no *HashMap*

```
private void storeTextView(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            storeTextView((ViewGroup) view);//Recursivamente percorre toda a Tree
        else if (view instanceof TextView) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            map.put(textView.getId(), textView);
        }
    }
}
```

Pegando no código do seu comentário seria assim:

```
Map<Integer,TextView> map = new HashMap<Integer, TextView>();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    v = adapter.getLayout(i);
    storeTextView((ViewGroup)v);
}
```

Parto do principio que os 7 layouts não se relacionam entre si, não fazem parte da mesma view.
Caso façam, basta passar para `storeTextView()` o layout mais alto na tree. Como é usada recursividade, todos os `TextView` são encontrados.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar...

Comment: ramaral, fiz como vc falou: *for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {v = adapter.getLayout(i); map.put(i, (LinearLayout)v);}* consegui acessar os 7 *layouts*, mas, infelizmente, acessar os *TextViews* neles não se tornou mais fácil

Comment: a partir do seu código consegui o que queria. Talvez não seja a forma ideal, mas achei mais fácil para mim. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.