# Referencias a vários EditText

Tags: android

É possível fazer referência de vários elementos de uma unica vez?

Ex:

Um array com todos as tags e outro com os EditText:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] tags = {"edit1", "edit2", "edit3"};

    //Um array de edittext, creio não ser possível, mas é só para o exemplo
    EditText[] editText = {edit1, edit2, edit3};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //E então fizer
        for (int i = 0; tags.length < i; i++){
            editText[i].findViewWithTag( tags[i] );
        }
        //Assim fazendo referencia a todos editText com um for
    }
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? Lembrando, esse exemplo acima do jeito que eu fiz não é possível, eu sei, é porque tenho mais de 20 EditTexts em um layout, e eu queria um modo mais simples de referenciar a todos.

Se houver um modo com o findViewById, pode ser também, mas creio que o com findViewWithTag seja mais fácil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o que quer é construir um array de EditText, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] tags = {"edit1", "edit2", "edit3"};

    //Um array para guardar os EditText
    EditText[] editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Construir o array
        for (int i = 0; tags.length < i; i++){
            editText[i] = (EditText)findViewWithTag( tags[i] );
        }

    }
}
```

Veja outras alternativas nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46631/2541).

Comment: Não posso declarar os nomes direto do array não? Mais ou menos como eu fiz no meu exemplo EditText[] editText = {edit1, edit2, edit3};

Comment: Não porque você não tem as referências. Para usar assim teria de ter uma variável do tipo EditText para cada um deles e obter as respectivas referências, usando `findViewById()`, antes de poder usá-las em `editText = {edit1, edit2, edit3};`